# Angular uib-typeahead is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have researched and looked through other solutions, but I cannot seem to get this to work still.

My primary issue is that the uib-typeahead seems to not work at all, either by just pointing to a return value or to a function (I'll include examples below).

I am using/inheriting Angular.UI.Bootstrap (v2.5.0) for this.

My HTML calls (trying with async and without) are:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="r.ResourceValueId as r.Value for r in ResourceValues | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control">



<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Resources" uib-typeahead="item.ResourceValueId as item.Value for item in getResourceValuesSearch($viewValue)" 
typeahead-loading="loadingResources" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingResources" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found</div>
```

Neither of the inputs have dropdowns that appear and the ResourceValues is populated (as tested with a normal "select"). For the async, it is not calling the getResourceValuesSearch() function at all.

UPDATE: I have both ngSanitize and ngAnimate included and running on the module as well. So the issue seems to be directly related to the angular-ui-typeahead as everything else seems to be working just fine.

Comment: any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: No, thats the odd thing. There are no errors, but it obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was having. I had the incorrect path for ui.bootstrap, although it did not return any errors...which I still find odd.

Either way, my issue was the wrong path for ui.bootstrap in my bundleConfig.

Answer (score 0):

write a service for calling Api and get the promise from it. use service in your function and return data.

Comment: I have both of those, and it works for everything else but the angular-ui-typeahead.